# Return all entry types or entry fields for one entry object

Tags: entries, field, entries-field

Is there a way to pull out all entry fields for an entry by their handle so they can be looped through?

For example rather than doing each field manually like `{{ entry.title }}`, `{{ entry.description }}` and `{{ entry.date }}`, just do a loop.

```
{% for field in entry %}
    {{ field.fieldHandle }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey Lettie, have at the question linked above and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Cheers @carlcs that's certainly helped. Quick question I want to also check if the field is a matrix field and then pull out all the block handles and content. I've tried:
    {% if field.fieldType == 'Matrix' %}
        <strong>Matrix Field: </strong>
    {% endif %}
But with no luck also tried just field.type and lower case matrix. What am I missing? Cheers.

Comment: Ignore that was almost there worked it out field.type == 'Matrix' thanks for you help.